# Why DeepLearning4J CNN is returning not probabilities but only 0s and 1s in the INDArray output

Tags: java, conv-neural-network, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I am playing with DL4J version 1.0.0-beta3 and trying to create a convolutional neural network for recognizing 32x32 images of chess pieces.
Here is the code I use to create and train the net:

```
public class BuildNetwork1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        File rootDir = new File("./CNNinput/chesscom1");
        
        File locationToSave = new File(rootDir, "trained.chesscom1.bin");
        
        int height = 32;
        int width = 32;
        int channels = 1;
        int rngseed = 777;
        int numEpochs = 100;
        
        File trainData = new File(rootDir, "training");
        
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                .seed(rngseed)
                .updater(new Adam.Builder().learningRate(0.01).build())
                .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                .list()
                //.layer(new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(new int[] {5, 5}, new int[] {1, 1}, new int[]{0, 0}).name("cnn1").nIn(1).nOut(64).biasInit(0).build())
                //.layer(new SubsamplingLayer.Builder(new int[] {2, 2}, new int[] {2, 2}).name("maxpool1").build())
                //.layer(new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(new int[] {5, 5}, new int[] {1, 1}, new int[]{0, 0}).name("cnn2").nIn(64).nOut(16).biasInit(0).build())
                .layer(new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                        .nOut(13)
                        .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                        .build())
                .setInputType(InputType.convolutional(32, 32, 1))
                .build();
        
        
        MultiLayerNetwork network = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
        
        network.init();
        network.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(10));
        
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(height, width, channels);
        DataNormalization scaler = new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1);
        
        for (int e = 0; e < numEpochs; e++) {
            File[] labels = trainData.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                File label = labels[i];
                File[] images = label.listFiles();
                for (int j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
                    File imageFile = images[j];
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
                    
                    INDArray input = loader.asMatrix(image).reshape(1, channels, height, width);
                    scaler.fit(new DataSet(input, null));
                    scaler.transform(input);
                    
                    double[][] outputArray = new double[1][13];
                    outputArray[0][Integer.parseInt(label.getName())] = 1d;
                    INDArray output = Nd4j.create(outputArray);
                    
                    network.fit(input, output);
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        boolean saveUpdater = true;
        ModelSerializer.writeModel(network, locationToSave, saveUpdater);
    }
}
```

And the code I am using in order to get the result:

```
public class CalcNetworkAll {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        int height = 32;
        int width = 32;
        int channels = 1;
        
        File rootDir            = new File("./CNNinput/chesscom1");
        File locationToLoad     = new File("./CNNinput/chesscom1/trained.chesscom1.bin");
        
        File testData = new File(rootDir, "testing");
        
        MultiLayerNetwork network = ModelSerializer.restoreMultiLayerNetwork(locationToLoad);
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(height, width, channels);
        DataNormalization scaler = new ImagePreProcessingScaler(0, 1);
        
        File[] labels = testData.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            File label = labels[i];
            File[] images = label.listFiles();
            for (int j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
                File imageFile = images[j];
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
                
                INDArray input = loader.asMatrix(image).reshape(1, channels, height, width);
                scaler.fit(new DataSet(input, null));
                scaler.transform(input);
                
                INDArray output = network.output(input, false);
                System.out.println(label.getName() + " => " + output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well and provides the expected outcome but my problem is that the output consists of 0s and 1s only instead of probabilities:

```
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,8.1707e-37,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
0 => [[    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
1 => [[         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
10 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
11 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
12 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
2 => [[         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
3 => [[         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
4 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
5 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
6 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
7 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
8 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
9 => [[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0]]
```

Do you have an idea why it happens?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is very confident in its output. This might happen when you are showing it data that it might have seen before and when you've trained your model to fit very well on that data (often called overfitting).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! The same confident output (with 0s and 1s) appears also when I test with arbitrary images of chess pieces but of course the output is wrong. At the end I am not able to receive probabilities whatever I try.

Comment: Because you are using an identity activation, my guess is that softmax gets very high input numbers, which are turned to 1/0 or so close to 1 or 0 that they effectively are that.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks again for the answer! I am using scaler in [0, 1] for the inputs, which I assume handles this issue, isn't it?

Comment: that puts your inputs into the 0..1 range, but after the multiplication with your weights it may be in any range.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks a lot! I succeeded to produce probabilities! Using Activation.TANH and uncommented the hidden layers from the code. I also have commented updater, because it works well with the defaults.